# is constexpr algorithm really useful, when iterator (input parameters) are not constexpr generally?

Tags: c++, c++20

proposed in c++ 20, some algorithms are constexpr.

For example:

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
bool all_of( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
(since C++11)
(until C++20)


template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
constexpr bool all_of( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
(since C++20)
```

While we know iterator are not constexpr generally. I think this is useful only in case of constexpr container. Can someone clarify if I am missing something and Whether my understanding is correct ?.

Comment: The iterator type is a template parameter which could be `your_custom_iterator` that has constexpr properties that will allow this function to be constexpr !

Comment: questions of opinion are off topic on stack overflow.

Comment: its not about opinion. As Oliver mention one reason which is good point.

Comment: @code707 it is absolutely an opinion.   "really useful" cannot be objectively answered.  Even if it it were objective, the question is also too broad for stack overflow because a full discussion of what could potentially make it useful (and whether that truly was useful) would be massive.

Comment: @xaxxon..there can be logical reason for being useful.

Comment: perhaps you have a more specific question you could ask.. like "is there any possible input which would allow this to be evaluated at compile time?" that would be a precise, objective question which could be answered in the affirmative with an example?  Or maybe take a shot at writing some code that would do that and if it isn't evaluated at compile time, post a question (along with the code) asking why.

Comment: Point taken. However, I dont have c++20 compiler so could not test things on my own. I will update question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure it is. Let's try another algorithm, which is not yet `constexpr` in C++20 to my knowledge, `std::iota`. But it's not too hard to define a `constexpr` version (I just copied the sample implementation from `cppreference` and slapped `constexpr` on it):

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class T>
constexpr void my_iota(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, T value)
{
    while(first != last) {
        *first++ = value;
        ++value;
    }
}
```

So is it useful? Yes it is. So long as the iterators are created as part of evaluating a constant expression, the evaluation of the algorithm can appear in a constant expression. For instance:

```
template<std::side_t N, typename T>
constexpr make_iota_array(T start = {}) {
  std::array<T, N> ret{};
  my_iota(ret.begin(), ret.end(), start);
  return ret;
}
```

The above creates an array initialized with the iota algorithm. If the function is called as part of evaluating a constant expression, the object `ret` is created as part of the evaluation, and so are its iterators. These are valid:

```
constexpr auto a1 = make_iota_array<10, int>();
constexpr auto a2 = make_iota_array<10>(0u);
```

Comment: Did this mean, that all operations on an iterator *must* also be constexpr if used for an constexpr algo

Comment: @Klaus no, only the ones you use