# Why isn't this std::string_view a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

I'm relatively new to `constexpr` programming and am trying to do some basic manipulation of `string_view` objects in a `constexpr` context. In my case, all of the strings start as literals in my source code, so it seems like they should be constant expressions. I found that I can construct a `constexpr string_view` from a string literal without any issue.

However, if I try to invoke a `constexpr` function that takes a `string_view` argument with a string literal, then compilation fails. See the below example ([Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/fzGhxs)):

```cpp
#include <string_view>

// this doesn't compile; the compiler complains that `sv` is not a constant-expression
constexpr bool foo(std::string_view sv) 
{
    constexpr auto it = sv.find('b'); 
    return it != sv.end();
}

// this compiles just fine, though
constexpr std::string_view bar("def");

int main()
{
    foo("abc");
}
```

gcc 8.3 provides the following error:

```
<source>: In function 'constexpr bool foo(std::string_view)':
<source>:5:32:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'sv.std::basic_string_view<char>::find(((int)'b'), 0)'
<source>:5:36: error: 'sv' is not a constant expression
     constexpr auto it = sv.find('b');
```

Why is the `string_view` argument to `foo()` not treated as a constant expression?

Comment: For reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/find

Comment: Inside of a function, its parameters are never considered to be constexpr. If you pass constexpr arguments to it, the only thing that could become constexpr is the return value.

Comment: That says `basic_string_view::find` is `constexpr`, though.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: If that's true, then it seems like it would be very difficult to do anything useful with `constexpr`; you would never be able to call a function that takes any arguments and use the result in a `constexpr` context. I'm probably missing something here.

Comment: You've just added obsolete `constexpr` https://godbolt.org/z/TKMxn8

Comment: @JasonR [Same for GCC 10.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39750eae3aa3dc78) (uncomment to see the error).

Comment: Just to clarify `sv.find('b');` can't be evaluated when compiling `foo` since value of `sv` is unknown when compiling `foo`. On other hand invocation of `foo(bar);` can be evaluated on compile time since in such case argument of `foo` is known.

Comment: You can do a lot with `constexpr` actually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491328/is-constexpr-algorithm-really-useful-when-iterator-input-parameters-are-not-c

Comment: *"it would be very difficult to do anything useful with constexpr"* No, I meant something else. Functions always work as if the arguments aren't constexpr, but if they actually are constexpr, then *the caller* can use the return value in a constexpr context. (Assuming the function doesn't do anything that can't be done at compile-time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `constexpr` object's value is required to *always* be a compile-time constant. Since the function `foo` doesn't have any control over what arguments are passed to it, the parameter `sv` cannot be considered a constant expression (the caller may pass a non-constant-expression argument) and thus cannot be used to define `it` as a `constexpr` object.

The `constexpr` specifier can simply be removed from the definition of `it`, and then `foo` will compile and can even yield a constant expression (provided that the argument is a constant expression). (A constant expression is allowed to reference non-`constexpr` objects, although it is not allowed to call non-`constexpr` functions.)

By the way, the name `it` should not be used here since it is misleading. `std::string_view::find` returns an index, not an iterator.

Comment: That makes sense, it just feels very awkward. This was a bit of a toy example, but I would like to be able to use the result of `find()` further in a `constexpr` context, for instance `static_assert(ind >= 0)`. In order to make it compile, I need to take any enforcement of `constexpr` out of the function body, and thus it needs to be done higher up the call stack where I can enforce that the return value is `constexpr`. Is there any way to simplify that? I would prefer to implement that logic in one place instead of every site where I call the function with a different literal.

Comment: Perhaps these are the sort of problems that C++20's `consteval` solves.

Comment: @JasonR yes, I think `consteval` is what you want in this situation. In C++17, I don't think there's any way to enforce constexprness of a `std::string_view` parameter. You cannot even promote such a parameter to a template parameter, since it doesn't satisfy the requirements to be a template parameter type.

Comment: I didn't collect much experience using `constexpr` functions in practice yet, but that sounds that there's a possibility lacking to guarantee that a paraneter to a `constexpr` function must be calculatable from another `constexpr` function, or should such function simply be inserted at the "call" directly?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I just see `consteval` mentioned.